# InfoPath Form workflow approval buttons disappeared

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, infopath, office-2016

I have a user who complained today that the workflow approval buttons she usually saw at the top of a completed InfoPath form (within the web browser) were missing today.  I don't do any of these approvals, but I also have not made any changes to the form in recent history, so I don't really know what might have made the difference.  The InfoPath forms are being filled as web forms within a SharePoint 2010 instance.  Recently everyone in the office was updated to Office 2016.

Other users simply go to the approval through Outlook and did not notice any difference.

Is this something that happened with a recent update to either Office or Windows Server, or some other patch?  (Our SharePoint 2010 instance has not been updated as recently as the other two things)